# LIST in recommenderlab is producing error

Tags: r, machine-learning

Working through the PDF document for the [recommenderlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/index.html) using this article:
(specifically page 12)
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.168.213&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I continue to get the following error:

```
> LIST(recom)
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘LIST’ for signature ‘"topNList"’
>
```

I have tried using `>list(recom)` instead...not the result I am looking for.

Any ideas on why this is not working like the CRAN-Package document suggests it should....
I am using R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01).

Comment: I don't see this example in the ref manual pdf. Where does this all-caps LIST come from? R is case-sensitive, btw. If you want to look inside a list, try `ls(recom)` or `names(recom)`...

Comment: There is no `LIST` function in the official documentation or the vignette on cran. Additionally, the **sos** package finds nothing at all by that name anywhere. I'd be willing to bet that the document you are using is either out of date, or it's a typo.

Comment: Sure enough, there's a function called `LIST` in an old version of the package. The current one has a function called `getList`. Maybe try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be too late for you, but you were reading an out of date paper.
Now, your solution would be like this:

```
as(recom,"list")
```

My best,
~L